# Delete files with specific string in them

Tags: batch, vbscript

I need to delete files which have the string ST*823 in them.

This does not seem to work:

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('findstr /m ST*823 *.txt') do del "%%F"
```

I don't think it likes the * since if I simply say ST then it works.

Answer (score 1):

FINDSTR will interpret the search string as a regular expression if it contains an unescaped regex meta-character (the `*` in your case). The `/L` option will force it to use a literal string interpretation.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('findstr /ml "ST*823" *.txt') do del "%%F"
```